# VSCode how to change size of explorer scrollbar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VSCode 1.58.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

VSCode 1.58 allows [Editor scroll bar customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58#_editor-scroll-bar-customization) which is great. However, this has no effect on the vertical scrollbar in the Explorer pane. Is there a setting to change the size of that scrollbar?

[image: VSCode, Explorer pane, vertical scrollbar]